# Override a text-align property

Tags: html, css

I would like to override a `text-align` property in my code. I have this HTML-code:

```
<style>
    table { text-align: center; }
    .align_left { text-align: left; }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="align_left">Align left ?</td>
        <td>Align center ?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: you got it right, that should work fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you don't have to override anything in the sample of code you gave us. It seems perfectly fine.

However if you ever need to override a CSS rule, you have multiple ways to do it:

- By setting a rule with higher [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

  table td.align-left { text-align:left }
  vs
  td { text-align:left }
- By setting a rule with the same level of specificity but later in the stylesheet

  table td { text-align:left } 
  table td { text-align:center } /* this line overrides the one above */
- By setting `!important`

  table td { text-align:left !important }

Answer (score 2):

```
td {text-align:center;}
td.align_left { text-align:left;}
```

If you are only targeting modern browsers you could also use :first-of-type to target the first td.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to override both the `table` and `.align_left` styles, or is `.align_left` something you've tried? The class should override the element:

```
table td { text-align:center; }
table td.align_left { text-align:right; }
```